# Excel vba combobox searching

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a main workbook and a sub book in Excel. I have my userforms on both the work books. Problem here is, I am opening a userform in main book and through that user form I want to open this sub book. I done it successfully; I have a combobox to search: so it's showing me an error sometimes:

> type missmatch:

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub 
    ComboBox2.DropDown
    Sheets(1).Select
    Application.Goto "R1C1"

    Dim r As Range, v() As Variant, s() As String
    'Set r = Range("InSheetDropDownList")
    Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", _
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    v() = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(r)

    On Error Resume Next

    With ComboBox2
        If .Value = "" Then .List = v()
        s() = Filter(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.List), .Text, True, vbTextCompare)
        If UBound(s) = -1 Then
            .Text = ""
        Else
            .List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(s)
       End If
   End With
  'ComboBox2.DropDown
End Sub
```

Comment: i am new to this website. i hope i would be helped soon. thank you

Comment: Else
            .List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(s)
        End If
    End With
    'ComboBox2.DropDown
End Sub

Comment: You may use the **edit** “button” (that one between *share* and *close*) to add details to your post or otherwise modify it. Comments are not well suited for improving the question.

Comment: Is it possible that sometimes, you are putting a range with more than one column?

Comment: @AntonSamsonov - "between share and close" should probably be "to the right of share" for a 1 rep user.  (I can't remember back that far very well, but I don't think "close" or "flag" would be displayed.)

Comment: (a) How does `Private Sub`, with no subroutine name, work sometimes?  (b) Is `Sheets(1)` always a `Worksheet`, or is it sometimes a `Chart`? (c) Which line gives the "type mismatch" error?